# List of Child Elements of a Element in ASIS(Ada Semantics interface Specification)

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, ada, semantics, gnat, asis

I am implementing a simple tool using ASIS(Ada Semantics interface Specifications).
I am having problem with listing child elements in a given Elements.for example i am having assignment statement as
        `C := A + B;`
i am able to get the element(expression) which represents "A + B", from the above assignment statement but need to extract A, B elements individually from the above expression.
what is the query in ASIS for doing the same. i have tried "Traverse_element" but not able to succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A + B` is a function call, so you have to extract the actual parameters of the function call using:

```ada
declare
   use ASIS.Expressions;
begin
   for Parameter_Association of Function_Call_Parameters (Expression => Element,
                                                          Normalized => True) loop
     declare
        Formal : constant Asis.Element := Formal_Parameter (Parameter_Association);
        Actual : constant Asis.Element := Actual_Parameter (Parameter_Association);
     begin
        ...
     end;
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Does the method will work, if the expression contains more functions(eg : A + B*C)?

Comment: Yes, but then one of the actuals will be a function call.